# Background image scale html5 css3

Tags: html, css

I've been messing with some html5 / css3 transitions and for the life of me i cant make the background image zoom in when hovering over the text what am i doing wrong is it possible this way ? or am i completely off route

code below.....

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.img-holder {
width: 400px;
height: 298px;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 10px;
position: relative;
color:white;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
font-size:20px;
font-weight:bold;
}
.img-holder img {
transform: scale(1);
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.img-holder img:hover {
transform: scale(1.1);
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.texthover {
position: absolute;
padding: 20px;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
display:-moz-box;
}
.img-holder:hover {
color:red;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
</style>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="img-holder"><a href="#"><img src="http://image.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/516040/96143585/stock-photo-dj-mixes-the-track-in-nightclub-at-party-96143585.jpg"/></a>
  <div class="texthover">Here's some text!!</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would reorder the elements in the HTML and use the adjacent sibling combinator to select the succeeding `img` element when hovering over the text (`.texthover:hover + img`).

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/t5fZc/)

```
.img-holder img:hover, .texthover:hover + img {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

If you *only* wanted the transformation to occur when hovering over the text, you would just use:

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/YKY4t/)

```
.texthover:hover + img {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Josh i've been pulling my hair out on this one you are a star :)